# i am getting error when i try to create web service client in Spring STS

Tags: spring

i am getting this error when try to create new web service client.
IWAB0503E Unable to update Java build path. Please check your system environment.

Comment: Which os? Maybe problems with file permission.

Comment: @jeans thanks for reply. I am using windows 7

Comment: i do not think that problem with file permission.

Comment: Can you change the buildpath by STS gui?

Comment: i did but same error :(

Comment: So it looks like file permissions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some web searching uncovered that what this error really means is “The Web Services generation tool detected multiple versions of the javax.xml.soap plug-in installed. Resolve this error by removing the conflicting plug-in.”

Sure enough, when I checked in Eclipse there were two versions.

[WebService](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAOrE.jpg)

I encountered two speed bumps when testing this theory:

There’s no easy way to uninstall a plug-in within the Eclipse UI, so I had to resort to removing the directory from eclipse\plugins directly from Windows Explorer.
Which version should I remove? It took me two tries to figure out which version was causing the error. Turns out that newer is not always better…in this case 1.3 was at fault and 1.2 (javax.xml.soap_1.2.0.v200905122109) was the version to keep.

Comment: This fixed my issue. Thanks. I removed the newer version of the java.xml.soap plug in.

Comment: Just after remove plugin, restart eclipse ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is old but, in my case the details of the error were:

IWAB0503E Unable to update Java build path. Please check your system environment.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /lib/**saaj.jar**

So \lib\saaj.jar was not found in folder
C:\sts-4.8.0\sts-4.8.0.RELEASE\plugins\javax.xml.soap_1.3.0.v201105210645\

I created the folder **lib** and copied saaj.jar in it from another STS instance that I had and then it worked.